# Calculate ratio between the distance of a line drawn by selection of two points to curved line drawn

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I want a page where an user will select two points and the distance will be measured.(only mousedown and mouseup event)
After that the user will draw a line using clicking(mousedown), moving(downmove) and releasing the click (mouseup).
Then a ratio will be calculated and shown in a label

Sharing the code I have written

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('#paint');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const sketch = document.querySelector('#sketch');
const sketch_style = getComputedStyle(sketch);
canvas.width = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('width'));
canvas.height = parseInt(sketch_style.getPropertyValue('height'));
var pathLength = 0;
var distance = 0;

const mouse = {x: 0,  y: 0};
const last_mouse = {x: 0,  y: 0};
const initialPoint  = {x: 0,  y: 0};

function distanceBetween(A, B) {
    const dx = B.x - A.x; 
    const dy = B.y - A.y; 
    return (dx * dx + dy * dy) ** 0.5;
}


/* Drawing on Paint App */
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
ctx.lineCap = 'round';
ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  initialPoint.x = mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  initialPoint.y = mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
  pathLength = 0;
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onPaint);
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  drawStraightLine()
  canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onPaint);
}, false);

function displayLengths() {
    StraightLineDistance.textContent = "Straight Distance: " + distance.toFixed(0) ;
    CurvedLineDistance.textContent = "Curved Distance: " + pathLength.toFixed(0) ;
    StIndex.textContent ="Straightness Index : " + (distance/pathLength);

}

function onPaint(e) {
  last_mouse.x = mouse.x;
  last_mouse.y = mouse.y;

  mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
  mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

  ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineTo(last_mouse.x, last_mouse.y);
  ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
  ctx.stroke();

  pathLength += distanceBetween(last_mouse, mouse);
  distance = distanceBetween(initialPoint, mouse);
  displayLengths();
};


function drawStraightLine() {
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF000077";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineTo(initialPoint.x, initialPoint.y);
  ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
  ctx.stroke();

  distance = distanceBetween(initialPoint, mouse);
  displayLengths();  
}
```

My code determines the length of the curved line and straight line.
What I need is the straight line distance between two clicked points and then a curved line distance drawn on canvas and their ratio in a label in html.

Sharing my HTML here

```
<html>
    <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="1.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="center" id="sketch">
  <canvas id="paint"></canvas>
  <script src="1.js"></script>
</div>
<label id="StraightLineDistance"></label><br/>
<label id="CurvedLineDistance"></label><br/>
<label id="StIndex"></label>
    </body>

</html>
```

I want the Straightline(two point distance)in the StraightLineDistance Label and the drawn line in CurvedLineDistance Column

Comment: What is the problem? What is the question?

Comment: See, my requirement is 1. The user will click on two points. The distance will be calculated between two points. 2. After the point clicking length is determined the user will draw a line whose code is already there and the distance of the curved line will be determined. 3. After that ratio of the point to point distance to the curve line distance will be determined and the canvas will be frozen so that one cannot draw two curved lines